# Play DTMF tone locally using ENUM_DTMF_MOTHOD_INFO

Tags: android, dtmf, portsip

When using the INFO method for DTMF, no sound is played locally.
Changing it to RFC2833 will play the sound locally but this method doesn't work with our SIP server.

How can I play the DTMF tone locally with the INFO method?

https://www.portsip.com/docs/html_man/android/html/group__group7.html#ga039f8725ec3a1f8811d0f4013a56f046

```
//      sdk.sendDtmf(currentLine.getSessionId(), PortSipEnumDefine.ENUM_DTMF_MOTHOD_RFC2833, code, 160, true);
        sdk.sendDtmf(currentLine.getSessionId(), PortSipEnumDefine.ENUM_DTMF_MOTHOD_INFO, code, 160, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own code to play a wav/mp3 file for the tone.